# Hyperlink area not clickable in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, hyperlink

In the following example, the word Test is not clickable in Internet Explorer, even though the link URL appears at the bottom of the page when it's hovered over, and the link's area is represented accurately in the horrible IE debugging tool (F12). This works fine in all other browsers (of course).

`<a href="/"><table><tr><td>Test</td></tr></table></a>`

I know it's not technically valid to nest a table inside a hyperlink tag, but it's really the only practical way to do what I want to accomplish, and seeing how it works fine in all browsers, is there a way to get it to work in IE?

So far, I've tried giving both the table and link a height, width, and also a display property of inline-block. None have worked. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Whatever it is, this is not the way to do it from a UI perspective...

Comment: I'm trying to prevent creating 3 separate links to the same page. There are 2 cells in my table, the left one contains an image, the right one contains a product title and "details" button. I want the entire area to act as a one link. From a logical standpoint, it makes sense that everything inside an <a /> tag be clickable. Regardless of technicalities, FF and Chrome allow this behavior.

Comment: Maybe you could use something like a ListView with a clickable row? You'd get much cleaner markup and the functionality you're seeking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say "seeing how it works fine in all browsers" -- but that's really not true. What's actually happening in some browsers is they're doing work to make it work.

Do something like this instead:

```
<table onclick="location.href='/'" style="cursor: hand;">
<tr><td>Test</td></tr>
</table>
```

Also a hack, but a more valid one.

**UPDATE**

If you have concens about crawlers, there are two possible approaches. One is to add a link after, something like:

```
<table onclick="location.href='/'" style="cursor: hand;">
<tr><td>Test</td></tr>
</table>
<a href="/" style="display:none;">Test</a>
```

You can also use a `<link>` tag in the `<head>` of the document, something like:

```
<link href="/" rel="section" />
```

Or whatever link [`rel` type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-links) makes sense.

Additionally, HTML structured as you have in your question is invalid according to the spec. In terms of what works reliably and into the future, your code does not qualify. Code written more towards an eye on standards will work more reliably.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Given your comment, here's how I would structure this, assuming markup like this:

```
<table class="dataTable">
    <tr>
       <td><img></td>
       <td>Description</td>
       <td><a href="/" class="details">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Your details link represents the link you're using, so what I would do is add this bit of JavaScript (uses jQuery, but could be rewritten for whatever libraries you're currently using:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
  $('table.dataTable').delegate('td', 'click', function(){
    $(this).find('a.details').trigger('click');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: My concern with this would be that some crawlers may not be able to crawl the onclick link, which would leave my pages un-indexed. I also disagree that it's "not really true," because it is absolutely true. It works fine in all other browsers, regardless of what they may be doing behind the scenes. This is one of many examples where IE does not accommodate something that all of the other major browsers do. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your concerns abour crawlers.

Comment: And an alternative approach using JavaScript.

Comment: this isn't bad. i used it minus the jquery. There are two minor problems... one is the url not showing above the status bar when you hover over the link, and the other is when you scroll-click the Details button, instead of opening only in a new tab, it also fires the table's onclick event. thanks.

Comment: You might include a `title` attribute on the table as a whole to address the issue of discoverability of the link. If you've removed jQuery, it's hard to speculate on what the right way to fix the factor of the event triggering twice.